# json_extract SQL in Cakephp

Tags: sql, cakephp

I need some help with a json_extract query. I'm trying to execute the following query from Cakephp 2 :

```
select * from certificates_types where json_extract(params, '$.params.invoice_date') > '2018-05-15'
```

I use Cakephp's query to do that :

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM certificates_types WHERE json_extract("params", "$.params.invoice_date") >= "2008-01-01"';
$types = $this->CertificatesType->query($query);
```

I only get the same error : "SQL Error: 3141: Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_extract: "The document is empty." at position 0". Did some of you used to face this problem ?

Comment: Why have you quoted `params` in the second version but not the first?

Comment: That's because I tried evrything :)

Comment: But I found a solution. The problem comes with the fact that some of my params are empty. This works in Mysql, but not in CakePhp. I solved it by adding "AND `params` <> '' "

Answer (score 0):

to use sql functions try this

> $query = $this->CertificatesType->find();
>
> $query->where(['CAST( JSON_UNQUOTE( JSON_EXTRACT(params,"$.params.invoice_date")) as DATE) >'=>'2018-05-15'])